# What is the account name for ASPNET in Windows 7?

Tags: asp.net, windows-7

I am trying to give the ASPNET user authority in certain folders on a Windows 7 box, but the usual name I am used to in WinXP, [ComputerName]\ASPNET, doesn't seem to work in W7.

Who can tell me the correct account name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you set your web application pool identity to. By default it's "IIS APPPOOL[AppPoolName]". Yes, IIS APPPOOL is the "domain".